# How do I open a project in Mavensmate using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: mavensmate, visualstudiocode

I'm having trouble getting VS Code to recognize any MavensMate tasks in my initial testings.  I definitely have the MM desktop app installed and a working project for it (I've been using MM and Sublime up until now).

For example, open a MM project

[image: Error: command 'mavensmate.openProject' not found]

What am I missing to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the GitHub issues list, looks like this is a known issue from a couple of months back, so hoping devs can resolve it soon.

Answer (score 3):

I just experienced this problem myself on Windows.  I resolved it by updating the VS Code path in the Mavensmate Desktop Settings (gear icon in the upper-right).

The path that worked for me was: **C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe**

Comment: This worked for me.  Although I had to restart my computer though since MavensMate was running in the background.

Comment: What path will work for the VS Code "executable" in macOS?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this question but is on macOS, you'll likely need to set this to `"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron"`